# OpenCV transform image shape transformation into a given contour

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, contour

Does anyone know whether it's possible to transform image A into image B contour if their shapes are random, using OpenCV or any other python libraries that work with images?

Here is what I have so far with 2 images:

[image]

I've been able to find draw contours of the bulb and insert a fox in it using `bitwise_and` method, but what it does is it crops the second image, whereas I need it to transform its shape into the bulb contour.

```
import cv2


src1 = cv2.imread('fox.png')
src2 = cv2.imread('bulb-contour-filled.png')

src2 = cv2.resize(src2, src1.shape[1::-1])

dst = cv2.bitwise_and(src1, src2)

cv2.imwrite('img_fin.jpg', dst)
```

Bulb original image:

[image]

Fox original image:

[image]

Bulb contour:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The Concept

For this we are going to need to slice the into triangles, and warp each triangle individually. The starting points of the image should be along the outline of the original image, and the ending points should be along the outline of the destination shape.

Although below I have hard-coded the 2 sets of points, you'll just need to figure out the optimal processing to retrieve the contours of the 2 images *(each needs have the same number of points and in the same order)*. Also, I have programmed an interactive OpenCV program that will allow us to easily retrieve the coordinates.

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def triangles(points):
    points = np.where(points, points, 1)
    subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D((*points.min(0), *points.max(0)))
    for pt in points:
        subdiv.insert(tuple(map(int, pt)))
    for pts in subdiv.getTriangleList().reshape(-1, 3, 2):
        yield [np.where(np.all(points == pt, 1))[0][0] for pt in pts]

def crop(img, pts):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(pts)
    img_cropped = img[y: y + h, x: x + w]
    pts[:, 0] -= x
    pts[:, 1] -= y
    return img_cropped, pts

def warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2):
    img2 = img2.copy()
    for indices in triangles(pts1):
        img1_cropped, triangle1 = crop(img1, pts1[indices])
        img2_cropped, triangle2 = crop(img2, pts2[indices])
        transform = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(triangle1), np.float32(triangle2))
        img2_warped = cv2.warpAffine(img1_cropped, transform, img2_cropped.shape[:2][::-1], None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
        mask = np.zeros_like(img2_cropped)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32(triangle2), (1, 1, 1), 16, 0)
        img2_cropped *= 1 - mask
        img2_cropped += img2_warped * mask
    return img2

def resize(img, size):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    return cv2.resize(img, (int(w * size), int(h * size)))

img1 = resize(cv2.imread("dog.png"), 0.8)
img2 = resize(cv2.imread("bulb.png"), 0.8)

pts1 = np.array([[322, 508], [390, 475], [413, 425], [440, 367], [453, 305], [458, 289], [446, 202], [434, 139], [392, 104], [324, 94], [246, 97], [194, 101], [111, 127], [98, 185], [88, 240], [95, 306], [90, 363], [123, 431], [160, 487], [223, 508]])
pts2 = np.array([[459, 793], [513, 715], [541, 580], [552, 470], [583, 398], [633, 323], [643, 233], [616, 144], [557, 71], [470, 28], [354, 27], [264, 72], [206, 138], [179, 225], [178, 302], [236, 401], [266, 480], [278, 564], [297, 707], [357, 792]])

cv2.imshow("result", warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### The Output

[image]

#### The Explanation

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function, `triangles`, that will take in an array of coordinates, `points`, and yield lists of 3 indices of the array for triangles that will cover the area of the original array of coordinates:

```
def triangles(points):
    points = np.where(points, points, 1)
    subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D((*points.min(0), *points.max(0)))
    for pt in points:
        subdiv.insert(tuple(map(int, pt)))
    for pts in subdiv.getTriangleList().reshape(-1, 3, 2):
        yield [np.where(np.all(points == pt, 1))[0][0] for pt in pts]
```

3. Define a function, `crop`, that will take in an image array, `img`, and an array of three coordinates, `pts`. It will return a rectangular segment of the image just large enough to fit the triangle formed by the three point, and return the array of three coordinates transferred to the top-left corner of image:

```
def crop(img, pts):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(pts)
    img_cropped = img[y: y + h, x: x + w]
    pts[:, 0] -= x
    pts[:, 1] -= y
    return img_cropped, pts
```

4. Define a function, `warp`, that will take in 2 image arrays, `img1` and `img2`, and 2 arrays of coordinates, `pts1` and `pts2`. It will utilize the `triangles` function defined before iterate through the triangles from the first array of coordinates, the `crop` function defined before to crop both images at coordinates corresponding to the triangle indices and use the `cv2.warpAffine()` method to warp the image at the current triangle of the iterations:

```
def warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2):
    img2 = img2.copy()
    for indices in triangles(pts1):
        img1_cropped, triangle1 = crop(img1, pts1[indices])
        img2_cropped, triangle2 = crop(img2, pts2[indices])
        transform = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(triangle1), np.float32(triangle2))
        img2_warped = cv2.warpAffine(img1_cropped, transform, img2_cropped.shape[:2][::-1], None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
        mask = np.zeros_like(img2_cropped)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32(triangle2), (1, 1, 1), 16, 0)
        img2_cropped *= 1 - mask
        img2_cropped += img2_warped * mask
    return img2
```

5. Read in your images. Note that I have resized the images to better fit my screen. If you remove the resizing part, you'll need to use the program below to re-adjust the points and get the corrected sets of points:

```
def resize(img, size):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    return cv2.resize(img, (int(w * size), int(h * size)))

img1 = resize(cv2.imread("dog.png"), 0.8)
img2 = resize(cv2.imread("bulb.png"), 0.8)
```

6. Finally, define the 2 sets of points; the first set outlining the first image, and the second one outlining the second. Use the `warp` function defined before to warp `img1` to have its keypoints overlap with the kewpoints of `img2` and show the resulting image:

```
pts1 = np.array([[0, 0], [286, 0], [286, 198], [174, 198], [158, 116], [0, 97]])
pts2 = np.array([[80, 37], [409, 42], [416, 390], [331, 384], [291, 119], [111, 311]])

cv2.imshow("result", warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### Tools

Use the program below to manually drag the point onto each image, and see the warp effect in real-time. Of course, rather than manually doing this, you can detect the contours of the two images *(make sure that they have the same number of points and are in the same order)*:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def triangles(points):
    points = np.where(points, points, 1)
    subdiv = cv2.Subdiv2D((*points.min(0), *points.max(0)))
    for pt in points:
        subdiv.insert(tuple(map(int, pt)))
    for pts in subdiv.getTriangleList().reshape(-1, 3, 2):
        yield [np.where(np.all(points == pt, 1))[0][0] for pt in pts]

def crop(img, pts):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(pts)
    img_cropped = img[y: y + h, x: x + w]
    pts[:, 0] -= x
    pts[:, 1] -= y
    return img_cropped, pts

def warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2):
    img2 = img2.copy()
    for indices in triangles(pts1):
        img1_cropped, triangle1 = crop(img1, pts1[indices])
        img2_cropped, triangle2 = crop(img2, pts2[indices])
        transform = cv2.getAffineTransform(np.float32(triangle1), np.float32(triangle2))
        img2_warped = cv2.warpAffine(img1_cropped, transform, img2_cropped.shape[:2][::-1], None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101)
        mask = np.zeros_like(img2_cropped)
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, np.int32(triangle2), (1, 1, 1), 16, 0)
        img2_cropped *= 1 - mask
        img2_cropped += img2_warped * mask
    return img2

def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    pts = param
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        for pt in pts:
            dist = (pt[0] - x) ** 2 + (pt[1] - y) ** 2
            if dist < 225:
                active_pt[:] = pt
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        active_pt[:] = 0
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if np.any(active_pt):
            for pt in pts:
                if np.all(active_pt == pt):
                    pt[:] = active_pt[:] = x, y

def draw_circles(img, pts):
    img = img.copy()
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(pts):
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 15, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(img, str(i), (x - 10, y + 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 0), 2)
    return img

def resize(img, size):
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    return cv2.resize(img, (int(w * size), int(h * size)))

img1 = resize(cv2.imread("dog.png"), 0.8)
img2 = resize(cv2.imread("bulb.png"), 0.8)

pts_count = 20

pts1 = np.arange(pts_count * 2).reshape((pts_count, 2))
pts2 = np.arange(pts_count * 2).reshape((pts_count, 2))

active_pt = np.array([0, 0])

cv2.namedWindow("image 1")
cv2.setMouseCallback('image 1', draw_circle, pts1)
cv2.namedWindow("image 2")
cv2.setMouseCallback('image 2', draw_circle, pts2)

pause = False
while True:
    cv2.imshow('image 1', draw_circles(img1, pts1))
    cv2.imshow('image 2', draw_circles(img2, pts2))
    if not pause:
        try:
            cv2.imshow("result", warp(img1, img2, pts1, pts2))
        except:
            pass
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
    if key & 0xFF == ord("p"):
        pause = not pause
    
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Here is a rough demonstration of how it works *(sped up x4)*:

[image]

If the real-time warping is too slow on your computer, simply press the p key to pause the warp updating, and press it again to resume it.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation of the concept. The result is very nice. Though I've been trying to use the code with hardcoded coordinates and getting this error:
`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'insert'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt'. Expected sequence length 2, got 20
>  - Can't parse 'ptvec'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type`

Anyway, could you please point me to the direction of how the points setup can be automated on the contour? Let's assume we want 1000 points to be set.

Comment: @onegingene About your error: which images did you use? Did you use the code as it is?

Comment: Yes, I did not change anything, including these 2 images of the bulb and the fox.

Comment: @onegingene Can you post a screenshot of the full traceback?

Comment: Posted that in the original question section

Comment: @onegingene What is the output when you add `print(img1.shape)` and `print(img2.shape)`?

Comment: (540, 540, 3)
(540, 540, 3)

Comment: @onegingene Is it the second program or the first program in my post that you ran?

Comment: The first one under the "The Code"

Comment: @onegingene What environment are you using? Which opencv version?

Comment: opencv-contrib-python 4.5.5.62
opencv-python               4.5.5.62

Comment: @onegingene Keep removing parts and parts of the code, making sure that the error remains the same. Once the code is substantially less, posts a screenshot here.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems the issue is with this class:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/dbf/classcv_1_1Subdiv2D.html#a18a6c9999210d769538297d843c613f2

Comment: @onegingene Yes. I'm not sure why the code is throwing an error on your side. If you reduce the code down until it's minimal whilst still throwing that error, I might be able to look into it.

Comment: Can you please explain what this line does?

points = np.where(points, points, 1)

Comment: @onegingene It replaces any instance of `0` in the array with `1`. If you try to have `0`s in the array *(and remove the `np.where(points, points, 1` line)*, you'll get an error.

Comment: @onegingene By the way, did you solve the error? How?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242963/discussion-between-onegingene-and-ann-zen).